# Date/time picker in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, datetime

I am new to C++, and to help learn I am trying to create a simple to do list, with a deadline for each to do item. when the user creates a new item I would like them to be able to choose a deadline (both date and time) up to 1 week in the future which the program will then count down until.

could someone point me towards appropriate libraries that will allow me to achieve this?

Comment: I had looked at the chrono library, which I think will be suitable for working with the date and time...but it is the actual process of having the user choose a deadline date which I am not sure about. Ideally they would be able to choose a date from a datepicker like the one at https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: what _kind_ of user interface do you have>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From microsofts documentation:
[How to Create a Date and Time Picker Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)